# What is the purpose of W and 'WB' in Oracle File_Util?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to generate excel file from Oracle by FILE_UTIL. In Oracle document they gave some mode of operations like 
 W - Write
 R - Read
 WB -Write Byte
RB - Read Byte

Unable to understand the difference between W and WB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you mean the `UTL_FILE` package... if not can you link to the documentation you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you're referring to seems to the [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#ARPLS069), which says slightly more than you indicated in the question:

> Specifies how the file is opened. Modes include:
>
> - `r` -- read text
> - `w` -- write text
> - `a` -- append text
> - `rb` -- read byte mode
> - `wb` -- write byte mode
> - `ab` -- append byte mode

The documentation also [says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#ARPLS069):

> `byte_mode`  Indicates whether the file was open as a binary file, or as a text file

So the `b` indicates byte mode rather than text mode. The file is accessed as a character stream if it's in text mode, so the file should be encoded in the database character set, as it says in the operational notes for that package. And it's accessed as a binary stream in byte mode. Several methods, such as `get_line`, will raise an exception for a file opened in byte mode as a 'line' has no meaning for binary data.

So it you're processing a file that is text, which could be stored as a `CLOB`, then use the text-mode flags. If you're processing a file that contains binary data like an image or PDF, which could be stored as a BLOB, use the byte-mode flags.

Excel files contain binary data whether you have a `.xls` or `.xlsx` file, so you'd need to use byte mode. If you were generating a `.csv` file though, you'd probably want text-mode.